# Linux X server antialising problem with wine

Tags: linux, centos, wine, x-server

I am are using a windows program under linux via wine. The program runs fine with KDE. Didn't test it on gnome. Finally we wanted to start the program without KDE - something like kiosk mode, so users not to be able to use anything but this gui program. I do that by:

```
startx the_program.exe
```

The program runs and it works, but the fonts are not antialised at all. xfs server is started:

```
[root@mclive5 ~]# chkconfig --list|grep -i xfs
xfs             0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

"**startx firefox**" works just fine and with anti-aliasing.

Linux distribution is CentOS 5.5, wine is 1.2.1 (1.2.1-1.el5.rf from romforge)

Any ideas how to turn on antialising?

Comment: I think the answer is under 5.5.3: http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/x-fonts.html I'm mobile or I'd spell it out more.

Comment: I've read that. I tried to use <edit name="antialias" mode="assign">       <bool>false</bool></edit> in /etc/fonts/fonts.conf. I also have file /etc/fonts/conf.d/10-antialias.conf with this contents:<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <match target="font">
    <edit mode="assign" name="antialias"><bool>true</bool></edit>
  </match>
<match target="font">
  <edit mode="assign" name="autohint">
    <bool>true</bool>
  </edit>
</match>
</fontconfig>
it didn't help

Comment: The link you gave me shows how to turn off anti-aliasing for mono fonts in KDE, not how to turn it on when not using KDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!
I wrote this in a file named "wine.reg":

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
"FontSmoothing"="2"
"FontSmoothingOrientation"=dword:00000001
"FontSmoothingType"=dword:00000001
"FontSmoothingGamma"=dword:00000578
```

then I run:

```
wine regedit wine.reg
```

Works like charm